# Transition probabilities of a Markov Chain where distribution of $X_{n+1}$ given $X_n = i$ is uniformly distributed

Tags: markov-chains, uniform-distribution, transition-matrix

I have a Markov Chain with state space $0, 1, 2, \ldots, 12$ and transition behavior given by:

- For $0 \le i \le 11$, the distribution of $X_{n+1}$ given $X_n = i$ is uniform on $i+1, i+2, \ldots , 12$.
- $P(12, 0) = 1$.

I am trying to build the transition matrix, $\mathbb{P}$, knowing that the probability of moving from state $12 \rightarrow 0$ is $1$, **but how do I find the other transition probabilities to complete $\mathbb{P}$?**

Comment: It's $X_{n+1}$ that's uniformly distributed, not its distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If $\ p_{ij}=P\left(X_{n+1}=j\left|X_n=i\right.\right)\ $, then
$$
p_{ij}=\cases{0& if $\ 0\le j\le i< 12\ $ or $\ i=12, j\ne0\ $,\\
               \frac{1}{12-i}& if $\ i<j\le12\ $,\\
                1 & if $\ i=12, j=0\ $.}
$$
So the transition matrix is
$$
\hspace{-1em}\pmatrix{0&\frac{1}{12}&\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12} &\frac{1}{12}\\
0&0 &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11} &\frac{1}{11}\\
0&0 &0 &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10} &\frac{1}{10}\\
0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{9} &\frac{1}{9}\\
0&0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8}\\
0&0&0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{7} &\frac{1}{7} &\frac{1}{7} &\frac{1}{7} &\frac{1}{7} &\frac{1}{7} &\frac{1}{7}\\
0&0&0&0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{6} &\frac{1}{6} &\frac{1}{6} &\frac{1}{6} &\frac{1}{6} &\frac{1}{6}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{5} &\frac{1}{5} &\frac{1}{5} &\frac{1}{5} &\frac{1}{5}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 &0 &0 &\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 &0 &0 &1\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 &0 &0}\ .
$$